# accepts_nested_attributes_for is contradicting the relational database logic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

Ruby on Rails model logic conflicts with the relational database logic.

In Ruby on Rails, the model possessing the `belongs_to`, will have the foreign key in the database. So, the model:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :university
end

class University < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :university
end
```

Will have the migration file:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
    t.string :name
    t.references :university, foreign_key: true
end

class CreateUniversities < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
    t.string :name
end
```

And, logically, the student will have the University foreign_key in the database, like so:

```
Student
-id int (PK)
-name varchar
-University_id int (FK)

University
-id int (PK)
-name varchar
```

**So good so far**

The problem arises when I want `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the student model for referencing a University in the `_form.html.erb`. In order to use it, the host model, in this case Student, must have a `has_one` instead of a `belongs_to` for the referencing table. So it would become:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :university
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :university
end
```

Notice how, in order to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for referencing the university, the Student model **MUST** replace its `belongs_to :university` for a `has_one :university`, and University would have a `belongs_to :student`, instead of a `has_many :student`.

So in the migration file, Student would lose its reference to University, and the latter would have a reference to Student instead, like so:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
    t.string :name
end

class CreateUniversities < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
    t.string :name
    t.references :student, foreign_key: true
end
```

And the database would forcefully be:

```
Student
-id int (PK)
-name varchar

University
-id int (PK)
-name varchar
-Student_id int (FK)
```

Which is wrong, because there should be a one to many relationship from University to Student, not the other way around.

So, is there a way to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, without messing up the relational database logic by having to forcefully inverse the relations in the models ?

Comment: A university has many students. It doesn't have many universities. Is this code actually all consistent? [mre]

Comment: Re "University would have a belongs_to :student, instead of a has_many :student",  "Student would lose its reference to University" & "and the latter would have a reference to Student instead" Why?

Comment: Your associations are way off. `Student` should `belong_to :university` and `University` should `have_many :students`. The foreign key  also needs to be `university_id` not `University_id`. Read the [Rails guides on associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) so that you understand the basics and then you might be ready to tackle nested attributes which is a fairly advanced topic.

Comment: But then again you don't seem to understand the "relational database logic" here either. If you place a `student_id`column on universities a university can only ever have one student. If you place a `university_id` column on students a student can only belong to one university but a university can have many students.

Comment: @max The asker seems to know that the bad DB designs are bad, they are asking how to not get them while having accepts_nested, but they are arising because of unnecessary & wrong use of activerecord declarations. (And presumably University
has_many :university is a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for`[Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

So you might be having a slight mix up about which one you want to be the parent. If you make the student the parent with nested attributes for the university you would not be referencing the university but essentially creating a new university record or updating an existing one with the nested attributes you used in your student form.

```
One-to-one

Consider a Member model that has one Avatar:

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar
end

Enabling nested attributes on a one-to-one association allows you to create the member and avatar in one go:

params = { member: { name: 'Jack', avatar_attributes: { icon: 'smiling' } } }
member = Member.create(params[:member])
member.avatar.id # => 2
member.avatar.icon # => 'smiling'
```

So you would only be updating/creating new University records for each student you used those nested attributes on.

Here is for one-to-many:

```
One-to-many

Consider a member that has a number of posts:

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

You can now set or update attributes on the associated posts through an attribute hash for a member: include the key :posts_attributes with an array of hashes of post attributes as a value.

For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be instantiated, unless the hash also contains a _destroy key that evaluates to true.

params = { member: {
  name: 'joe', posts_attributes: [
    { title: 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { title: 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
    { title: '', _destroy: '1' } # this will be ignored
  ]
}}

member = Member.create(params[:member])
member.posts.length # => 2
member.posts.first.title # => 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!'
member.posts.second.title # => 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen'
```

You can also see that in the one to many example above. Are you looking to change/create a University record when you post a Student record?

If you are just looking for a reference you essentially have that in your first example and could just change your routes up a bit to have the student [referenced by the university](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Then once you have the routes nested you can just do a little work to the form partial. [Here is a guy doing just that](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-nested-resources-for-a-ruby-on-rails-application#step-4-%E2%80%94-modifying-views)

So maybe if I am way off here describe why when you create/update a Student you want to create/update a University. If that is what you want to do.

This would helps others with your context a little more and might help others understand your intent with the nested attributes.

Add your form partial for example and explain your goal.

**EDIT:**
[As a punt you can maybe look at has and belongs to many association.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)
[This tutorial talks about nested attributes with a many to many association.](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes) But since I'm not certain exactly what your after it may or may not help.

Another punt sounds like you want maybe a student's university record to change when you update them. So you would have the student belong to the university and the university to has many students but also has many university records and the student to has many/has one university record and the record to belong to both.
aka:
[this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Then you could have the student have accepts nested attributes for the university record/s.

Answer (score 0):

I see that I have REALLY made a blunder trying to explain my doubts (it is my first question, I have learned from my mistake).

The ultimate goal was to know:

Can I use accepts_nested_attributes_for when there is a **belongs_to** instead of a **has_one** or **has_many** ?

So, the answer is yes:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :university
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :university
end
```

In the student controller, there should be a build_:

```
  def new
    @student = Student.new
    @student.build_university
  end
```

I REALLY, REALLY, REALLY mistyped my question, and I apologize for it.

Thanks for all your answers.